# Express Static Middleware serves index.html automatically

Tags: node.js, express

I'm not very familiar with NodeJS and started to work with it and Express. Now I'm getting the following content: I want to serve an index.html file but make some other things before that. But since I'm using `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/public'));` a browser request does not affect the `app.get("/")` function. How do I solve that problem?

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/src/css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('###GET REQUEST received');
    console.log(req);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); 
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Order matters.  Put your app.get route prior to the Express.static declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much, so easy but didn't think about that!

Answer (score 8):

Or, disable the indexing.

```
express.static(path, {index: false})
```

> `index`: sends the specified directory index file; set to `false` to disable directory indexing.
>
> <sub>from https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static</sub>